# Spotfire Cross Table - How to implement Calculated expression column as a filter

Tags: spotfire

I am doing month to date recon. and my date is keep on changing which selected by the end user. I filter my dataset using the filter expression base on the date selected.

I used cross table and I have 2 column and compute the difference as expression column.

I also another column expression to validate the result if greater than or equal to 1000 I put Yes or No if not (@ column K1Over).

My dilemma is how to use the K1over colum as filter because I only want to display my data that 1000+ as difference or display < 1000

I try a pivot transformation and insert column but there is no sum expression when matching the columns.

Can you please help, or suggest how to implement scenario like this?

Here is sample scenario

```
Letter      Reported PNL     PAA Actual     DIFF(Calc)    K1Over (calc)

AAA        6000              5000           1000          YES                                     
BBB        8000              7500           500           NO - Hide filter out                                 
CCC        2000              1000           1000          YES
DDDD       1000              1000           0             NO- Hide filter out
```

Much appreciated. 
Leo

Comment: @Leo- Have you tried 'Limit data using expression' on the table to filter out rows whose DIFF is <1000. Also, you could use a document property as well. This line is not clear, could you explain more?  *I try a pivot transformation and insert column but there is no sum expression when matching the columns.*

Answer (score 0):

When you go into the Cross Table properties, the last category is called "Show/Hide Items".

Here, you should add a Rule, selecting your K1Over column, Rule type "Greater than or equal to", Value "1000", When this rule is matched; "Show items"

[image]